# How to compute drag coefficient for falling book?

Tags: aerodynamics

The book measures 20 x 20.3 x 1.4cm and I'm assuming it's sealed shut so the pages don't flap open. Mass is 450g.

I want to understand how quickly it would fall if dropped straight down from 10km altitude. I've used a value for drag coefficient for a flat plate perpendicular to the air flow that I got from NASA (1.28) but I'm guessing that a falling book would spin round, slowing its fall, so this value is probably not right - is this likely?

So I'm wondering if it's possible to estimate the drag coefficient to any degree of accuracy. I don't have access to a wind tunnel and I'd rather not drop it off a tower as an experiment. :)

Comment: Umm.. if the book tumbles and spends part of its time falling with say the spine pointing straight down, won't the average speed be much faster than suggested by your description?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, this is less ridiculous than other questions on the site, and makes for an ok though experiment.

Comment: Brings to mind a new possible question :"what is the purpose of a book"-- similar to "what is the purpose of a propeller"

Comment: Try physics.se for relevant answer as well.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica and others: this question is being discussed here: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3978/1467

Comment: Sorry but non-aviation aerodynamic questions are off topic here, see the [help] and linked meta post for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You have a very thin book. The answer depends on how you initially drop the book.

## 1. If you drop it flat about its front

It will very closely approximate a flat plate; in this case, the pressure drag will overwhelm the skin friction drag. *Hoerner*, Fluid Dynamic Drag has some empirical data on the drag coefficient of a bluff body (near 2.0):

[image: 2D drag coefficient]

To retrieve the 3D coefficient, dimensionalize it with the frontal area.

## 2. If you drop it broadside

The skin friction drag would dominate. You can approximate it via [the flat plate friction drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_friction_drag). For a single side, the drag coefficient looks like (from *Anderson*, Fundamentals of Aerodynamics):

[image]

## 3. If it tumbles

Your book may also tumble at some point due to random perturbation about its major principal axis. This changes the drag even further; but once again, *Horner* has some empirical correction formula.

Answer (score 1):

The book's pages won't flap open, but it will bend unpredictably, because its density is so close to that of paper (vs. hardboard) that it must be a paperback.  So you can't assume that it's a flat plate. Even if you fling it like a frisbee so centrifugal force holds it flat like [LightSail 2](https://www.planetary.org/blogs/jason-davis/ls2-deploys-sail.html), during a 10 km drop, air friction will overcome that and let it tumble chaotically.

I know of no drag measurements for variously curved thin plates at arbitrary angles of attack.  You might need to drop half-ounce paperbacks late at night in a tall building lobby to estimate lower and upper bounds for C<sub>D</sub>.

Comment: Thanks - it is in fact a hardback with 2mm board.

Comment: Huh.  Densities for hardboard that I found were a good deal less than for paper, but if these numbers come from your actual measurements, then you'd know!